# merge two local commits into single and push to master in git

Tags: git, commit, gerrit

I have two commits : commit1 and commit2 locally.

commit1 got merged. commit2 is on top of commit1.

now, when I am trying to push commit2, it is **trying to push two commits together** and it gets rejected from remote saying, that **commit1 has already been merged and remote rejects both the commits**. my intention is to keep the changes of commit1 in commit2 and push only commit2 to masted. how can i do that?

Comment: You push to remotes.  `master` is a branch. So it's unclear what you're trying to do.  Please clarify.  (Perhaps you're trying to push the changes directly from a branch to the remote's `master`?  But I'm not sure.)  More importantly, please show exact commands and error messages, because the error you described doesn't make sense as something git would say.

Comment: $git pull --rebase
..
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Commit Message 1
Applying: Commit Message 2

Comment: To ssh://gerritlink:29418/BRANCH
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/drafts/master (change https://gerritlink/320934 closed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://gerritlink:29418/BRANCH'

Comment: $ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

Comment: locally, i am in master branch

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear about this, but I don't think anybody is going to try to read the commands and output from comments; it's completely illegible and I for one am not spending time decoding it.  I would recommend *editing your question to provide an appropriate level of detail* about what is happening.

Comment: Please edit your question and add all commands/outputs to it. Do not forget to add the exact "git push" command you have used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since commit1 already merged/pushed into remote branch it is possible to update the local branch by rebasing it. `git pull -r` after that the commit2 can be pushed alone on top of commit1. `git push origin master:master` or in case of gerrit review `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`